# Stencil component not rendering the updated tabs

Tags: stenciljs, stencils, stencil-component

```js
import { Component, h, State } from '@stencil/core';
// import '@webcomponents/custom-elements';
import '@clr/core/icon/register';
import { ClarityIcons, plusIcon } from '@clr/core/icon';

ClarityIcons.addIcons(plusIcon);

@Component({
  tag: 'tabs-component',
  styleUrl: 'tabs-component.css',
  shadow: false,
})
export class TabsComponent {
  @State() tabs: Array<object> = [
    (
      <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
        <button id="tab3" class="btn btn-link nav-link" aria-controls="panel3"
          aria-selected="false" type="button">Cloud</button>
      </li>
    )
  ];

  addTab(onHead = true) {
    // debugger
    const tab = (
      <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
        <button id="tab3" class="btn btn-link nav-link" aria-controls="panel3"
          aria-selected="false" type="button">Dashboard</button>
      </li>
    );
    if (onHead) {
      this.tabs.unshift(tab);
    } else {
      this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
    console.log(this.tabs);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id="demoTabs" class="nav" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" onClick={() => this.addTab()}>
            <cds-icon shape="plus" class="cursor"></cds-icon>
          </li>
          {this.tabs}
        </ul>
        <section id="panel1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1">
          tab1
        </section>
        <section id="panel2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2" aria-hidden="true">
          tab2
        </section>
        <section id="panel3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3" aria-hidden="true">
          tab3
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stencil performs strict equality checks (`===`) to determine whether a Prop/State variable has changed which is why it doesn't detect `push` and `unshift` as changes. You have to make sure to replace the array with a new one. The quickest way to do this in your example is to manually replace the array with a copy after the manipulation:

```
    if (onHead) {
      this.tabs.unshift(tab);
    } else {
      this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
    this.tabs = [...this.tabs];
```

See [the Stencil docs for updating arrays](https://stenciljs.com/docs/reactive-data#updating-arrays).

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of referential equality. Objects are always passed by reference not by value and therefore two objects are never equal (reference-wise, even if they contain the same values).

The array is a special kind of object and therefore is also passed by reference. Modifying an array's value does not change its reference.

Some examples to illustrate this:

```js
const foo = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(foo === ['a', 'b', 'c']); // false

foo.push('c');
console.log(foo === ['a', 'b', 'c']); // still false

console.log(['a', 'b', 'c'] === ['a', 'b', 'c']); // actually always false

console.log(foo === foo); // always true because it is the same reference
```

Stencil compares `@State()` decorated class members using the same strict equality operator `===` (same goes for `@Prop()`). If the value is the same, then the component is not re-rendered.

In the case of your `tabs` state, the value of `this.tabs` is a reference to the array that you assign to it. Modifying the array (e. g. `this.tabs.push(...)`) only changes the value of the array referenced by `this.tabs` but not the actual reference that is stored in `this.tabs`.

Therefore you need to re-assign `this.tabs` in order to let Stencil know that this member has changed. The easiest way to do that is

```js
this.tabs = [...this.tabs];
```

which spreads the values of the array into a new array (which returns a new reference). Alternatively something like `this.tabs = this.tabs.slice()` would also do the trick (anything that returns a new array works).

In your case it's easiest to change your `addTab` method to

```js
addTab(onHead = true) {
  const tab = (
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <button id="tab3" class="btn btn-link nav-link" aria-controls="panel3"
        aria-selected="false" type="button">Dashboard</button>
    </li>
  );

  this.tabs = onHead ? [tab, ...this.tabs] : [...this.tabs, tab];
}
```

(i. e. either spread the original value before or after the new item).

Answer (score 0):

Look like temp variable works the trick, strange.

```js
    const tempTabs = [...this.tabs];
    if (onHead) {
      tempTabs.unshift(tab);
    } else {
      tempTabs.push(tab);
    }
    this.tabs = tempTabs;
```

Comment: This is not because there's a temp variable but because `tempTabs` holds a reference to a different array than `this.tabs` (with the same content). When you set `this.tabs = tempTabs`, you change the reference of `this.tabs`.